# Losing Session Variables during internet reconnection

Tags: asp.net

I have looked for help on this problem, but not found anything quite like it.

I have an asp.net web site which 1 user (that I know of) is getting problems with being logged out (forms auth) and losing session variables.

I think basically what is happening is the user is using a mobile internet connection, which is sometimes flaky and drops the connection and reconnects, sometimes but not always with a new ip address. I think this is destroying the values stored in session state.

Is this a problem anyone has had, and if so, how do you get round it? I guess it could get worse if more people connect to the internet in this way.

Often the error is the View state mac error, but not always.

Of course, it may not be related to internet connection issues.

Many thanks

Comment: How is the session ID stored on the client side and what mechanism for tracking sessions does your server use?

Comment: In MasterPage.PageLoad I am checking HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionId"] - if it is null I write a session record to the database and store the ID from that in this ["SessionId"]

Comment: A new session would start with every connection, unless you set the site up to save the session state.  You could use cookies as an alternative.  Also, you could create a setup like is used for a web farm.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I don't think the hosting company will allow me to change these settings for State Server Mode or SQL Server Mode - but I could write my own. If I store the SessionId in a cookie, and then read and write vars that I would normally put into Session State, from the Database. I think this would work but is it bad practice/inefficient?

Comment: Network connectivity/IP addr will not affect session (unless of course the session expires before reconnection). Learn more about the client that has issue - its more likely an issue at the client side - e.g. privacy software (kills cookies whenever it likes - sessions are cookies on the client side, unless of course you are implementing cookieless sessions).

Comment: cookieless sessions are the ones where the urls are crazy looking